# access only first 80% columns of a data frame

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, dataframe, recommendation-engine

I want to access only the first 80% columns of my dataframe and store it into new data frame  whereas store the remainig 20% in another data frame. Here is something I tried:

```
ratings_df=ratings_df.iloc[:,:int(ratings_df.shape()[1]*0.8)-1]
```

however this gave an error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "S:\TIP\Code\MF_research.py", line 15, in <module>
    ratins_df=ratings_df.iloc[:,:int(ratings_df.shape()[1]*0.8)-1]
TypeError: 'tuple' object is not callable
```

ratings_df:

```
MovieID  1     2     3     4     5     6     ...  3947  3948  3949  3950  3951  3952
UserID                                       ...                                    
1         5.0   0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0  ...   0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0
2         0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0  ...   0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0
3         0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0  ...   0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0
4         0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0  ...   0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0
5         0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0   2.0  ...   0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0
...       ...   ...   ...   ...   ...   ...  ...   ...   ...   ...   ...   ...   ...
6036      0.0   0.0   0.0   2.0   0.0   3.0  ...   0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0
6037      0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0  ...   0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0
6038      0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0  ...   0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0
6039      0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0  ...   0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0
6040      3.0   0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0  ...   0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0

[6040 rows x 3706 columns]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should remove the brackets. You only need df.shape[1].
By the way for more readability, I suggest you use rather

```
shape_80 = int(df.shape[1]*0.8)-1
ratings_df=ratings_df.iloc[:,:shape_80]
```

Or something like that

Answer (score 1):

You can use .shape method to get all row and columns.

`ratings_df.shape` returns (rows count,columns count) and if you select second element of tuple by using `[1]`, you get all row counts

```
df1 = ratings_df.iloc[:,:round(0.8*ratings_df.shape[1])]
df2 = ratings_df.iloc[:,round(0.2*ratings_df.shape[1]):]
```

Answer (score 1):

If the order of the columns does not matter you can try a very short solution:

```
df.sample(frac=0.8, axis=1)
```

Answer (score 0):

- **To Split by COLUMN:**
  This can be one way to split one DataFrame into Two DataFrames.

```
import pandas as pd 
  
# intialise data of lists. 
data = {'Name':['A', 'B', 'C'], 
        'Age':[20, 24, 21],
        'Sex': ['M', 'F', 'M'],
        'Group': ['Science', 'Arts', 'Science']} 
  
# Create DataFrame 
df = pd.DataFrame(data)

valuesArr = df.values
columnsArr = df.columns

arr80 = valuesArr[:, 0:int(len(columnsArr)*0.80)]
arr20 = valuesArr[:, int(len(columnsArr)*0.80):]

df80 = pd.DataFrame(data=arr80, columns=columnsArr[0:int(len(columnsArr)*0.80)])
df20 = pd.DataFrame(data=arr20, columns=columnsArr[int(len(columnsArr)*0.80):])

print(df80)
print(df20)
```

```
OUTPUT:
  Name Age Sex
0    A  20   M
1    B  24   F
2    C  21   M
     Group
0  Science
1     Arts
2  Science
```

- **To Split by ROW:**
  If you want to split the dataframe using the rows instead of columns then it can be a way to do it.
  I hope it helps someone!

```
import pandas as pd 
  
# initialise data of lists. 
data = {'Name':['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F', 'G', 'H', 'I', 'J'], 
        'Age':[20, 24, 21, 19, 18, 21, 19, 19, 20, 30]} 
  
# Create DataFrame 
df = pd.DataFrame(data)

valuesArr = df.values

arr80 = valuesArr[:int(len(valuesArr)*0.80)]
arr20 = valuesArr[int(len(valuesArr)*0.80):]

df80 = pd.DataFrame(data=arr80, columns=df.columns)
df20 = pd.DataFrame(data=arr20, columns=df.columns)

print(df80)
print(df20)
```

```
OUTPUT:
  Name Age
0    A  20
1    B  24
2    C  21
3    D  19
4    E  18
5    F  21
6    G  19
7    H  19
  Name Age
0    I  20
1    J  30
```

Comment: Hey but this gives first 80% rows, I want all rows and only first 80% columns!

Comment: ahh, my bad. yeah, just realized you asked for columns. Anyways, I will keep the comment in case it helps someone!